# The relationship between zero level set and thickness information

Tags: algorithms, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have one problem that need you help. I am try to find the relationship between active contour and thickness information. For defination of thickness we can find at [thickness measuring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735748/measuring-the-average-thickness-of-traces-in-an-image) and active contour at [chan-vese model](http://cdanup.com/10.1.1.2.1828.pdf). Could you sugess me method or idea to find the thickness of active contour (is called phi) as show in figure

[image]